# What are the possible right/left inverses of $f(n) = n-1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Define a function $f(n)=n-1$ for integer $n≥2$. What are all possible right  inverses for $f$? How about left inverses? I know $g=n+1$ is a left and right inverse of $f$. But is it unique on both sides?

Comment: That depends on what you chose as codomain for your function.

Comment: @celtschk Hi, can you elaborate on it? I have no clue at all right now. Thank you!

Comment: Your function is an injection (if the function values are the same, the arguments are also the same). If you chose the codomain to equal the image, it is a bijection, and therefore has an unique inverse. If you chose your codomain larger, then it is no longer surjective, and thus has no right inverse, but many left inverses.